# Queryable source of large cities

Tags: data-request, geospatial, api, city

I'm trying to get a list of major cities in the world: their name, population, and location.  I found what looked like a good query on [Wikidata](https://query.wikidata.org/#%23Largest%20cities%20of%20the%20world%0A%23defaultView%3ABubbleChart%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3FcityLabel%20%3Fpopulation%20%3Fgps%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fcity%20%28wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279*%29%20wd%3AQ515.%0A%20%20%3Fcity%20wdt%3AP1082%20%3Fpopulation.%0A%20%20%3Fcity%20wdt%3AP625%20%3Fgps.%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28%3Fpopulation%20%3E%3D%20500000%29%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%0AORDER%20BY%20DESC%28%3Fpopulation%29), slightly tweaking a built-in query example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?cityLabel ?population ?gps WHERE {
  ?city (wdt:P31/wdt:P279*) wd:Q515.
  ?city wdt:P1082 ?population.
  ?city wdt:P625 ?gps.
  FILTER (?population >= 500000) .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
ORDER BY DESC(?population)
```

The results, at first glance, appear to be good, but it's missing a ton of important cities.  For example, San Francisco (population 800,000+) is not in the list, when I specifically asked for all cities with a population greater than 500,000.

Is there something wrong with my query?  If not, there must be something wrong with the data Wikidata is using.  Either way, how can I get a valid data set, with an API I can query from a Python script?  (I've got the script all working for this; I'm just not getting back valid data.)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Andrew for pointing a way to check data.

You can have 'San Francisco' and two other cities changing your query to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?cityLabel ?population ?gps WHERE {
  ?city (wdt:P31/wdt:P279*) ?type.
  ?city wdt:P1082 ?population.
  ?city wdt:P625 ?gps.
  FILTER (?population >= 500000) .
  FILTER(?type=wd:Q515 || ?type=wd:Q3301053)
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
ORDER BY DESC(?population)
```

the changes are: **?type** and **FILTER(?type=wd:Q515 || ?type=wd:Q3301053)**

**(your query gives 251 entries, after change: 254)**

Comment: SF does have a population value (several of them, in fact) - https://m.wikidata.org/wiki/Q62 ; it's also correctly marked P31:Q515 so the search should pick it up.